# Unit test lazy loaded component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, lazy-loading, angular9

I'm loading a component and its module lazily with the following code snippet:

```
@ViewChild(TemplateRef, { read: ViewContainerRef })
private templateViewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;

constructor(
  private readonly componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
  private readonly injector: Injector
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.loadModuleAndComponent();
}

private async loadModuleAndComponent() {
  import('@scope/package').then(({ LazyModule, LazyComponent }) => {
    // load module to set up store etc.
    createInjector(LazyModule, this.injector).get(LazyModule);

    // create component instance
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(LazyComponent);
    const componentRef = this.templateViewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  

    // set data of the component
    // how to test?
    componentRef.instance.data = {};

    // handle emitted events
    // how to test?
    componentRef.instance.actionPerformed
      .asObservable()
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((action) => {});
  });
}
```

While this is working fine, I'm unsure how to test the input (i.e., the component got `data`) and emitted events (i.e., the `actionPerformed` events) of the `LazyComponent` in this component.

Before Angular 9, I guess that using the [SpyNgModuleFactoryLoader](https://angular.io/api/router/testing/SpyNgModuleFactoryLoader) was the way to go, but [NgModuleFactoryLoader](https://angular.io/api/core/NgModuleFactoryLoader) is now deprecated.

You can find a [running example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lazy-load-module-component?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: Since you are loading component you need to mount it somewhere (I suppose). Therefore you simply need to get this component from DOM and get its state. There is `debugElement.query(By.directive())` that you can use to get your component/directive

Comment: Then you simply init the test. Run loading code. `flush()` so that all requests are done. Ensure that fixture is stable and you are ready to go

Comment: If you are mounting the component using Portal or wharever other place rather than your component's scope you could just intercept the method call wih `Spy` and ensure the component's state